# Updating BigDecimal concurrently within ConcurrentHashMap thread safe

Tags: java, concurrency

Is the code below thread/concurrency safe when there are multiple threads calling the `totalBadRecords()` method from inside other method? Both map objects parameters to this method are `ConcurrentHashMap`. I want to ensure that each call updates the total properly.

If it is not safe, please explain what do I have to do to ensure thread safety.

Do I need to synchronize the add/put or is there a better way?

Do i need to synchronize the get method in TestVO. TestVO is simple java bean and having getter/setter method.

Below is my Sample code:

```
public void totalBadRecords(final Map<Integer, TestVO> sourceMap,
            final Map<String, String> logMap) {


        BigDecimal badCharges  = new BigDecimal(0);
        boolean badRecordsFound = false;

        for (Entry<Integer, TestVO> e : sourceMap.entrySet()) {
            if ("Y".equals(e.getValue().getInd()))
                badCharges = badCharges.add(e.getValue()
                        .getAmount());
            badRecordsFound = true;
        }

        if (badRecordsFound)
            logMap.put("badRecordsFound:", badCharges.toPlainString());

    }
```

Comment: Will the multiple threads be calling the method *with the same arguments?* And if so, why?

Comment: I dont understand your question ,Here arguements means map objects.Map objects may have different data for each thread call

Comment: I don't see the point of using a `BigDecimal` here.  You can't *possibly* get an "badCharges" count that is greater than can be represented using a `long`.  (A `ConcurrentHashMap` can't get that big.  You'd run into some hard JVM architectural limits first.)

Comment: Your conceptual mistake is to think you can make just one method thread-safe without looking at the rest of your application. The question is which parts of your application might change the map while this method is iterating over it and how to prevent them from doing so. It doesn’t help to just add a lock to this method as the *other* parts of your application must acquire that lock correctly before mutating your data, otherwise it’s pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how your objects are used in your whole application.

If each call to `totalBadRecords` takes a different `sourceMap` and the map (and its content) is not mutated while counting, it's thread-safe:

- `badCharges` is a local variable, it can't be shared between thread, and is thus thread-safe (no need to synchronize `add`)
- `logMap` can be shared between calls to `totalBadRecords`: the method `put` of `ConcurrentHashMap` is already synchronized (or behaves as if it was).
- if instances of `TestVO` are not mutated, the value from `getValue()` and `getInd()` are always coherent with one other.
- the `sourceMap` is not mutated, so you can iterate over it.

Actually, in this case, you don't need a concurrent map for `sourceMap`. You could even make it immutable.

If the instances of `TestVO` and the `sourceMap` can change while counting, then of course you could be counting wrongly.

Comment: the map (and its content) is not mutated while counting means other thread not change during that call or while iterating this map doing any put operations? .TestVO having simple setter methods. But it creates new object for other thread call.Still synchronization issue comes?

Comment: @user2750658 When a thread counts the bad records in a sourceMap and its TestVO, no other thread should modify the map and its TestVO concurrently.

Comment: @user2750658 I suggest your change your design to make TestVO and the sourceMap immutable.

Comment: TestVO and sourceMap i declared as final .I know TestVO properties are not threadsafe. How to make these 2 objects are immutable?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by thread-safe.  And that boils down to what the *requirements* for this method are.

At the data structure level, the method will not corrupt any data structures, because the only data structures that could be shared with other threads are `ConcurrentHashMap` instances, and they safe against that kind of problem.

The *potential* thread-safety issue is that iterating a `ConcurrentHashMap` is not an atomic operation.  The guarantees for the iterators are such that you are not guaranteed to see all entries in the iteration if the map is updated (e.g. by another thread) while you are iterating.  That means that the `totalBadRecords` method may not give an accurate count if some other thread modifies the map during the call.  Whether this is a *real* thread-safety issue depends on whether or not the `totalBadRecords` is *required* to give an accurate result in that circumstance.

---

If you need to get an accurate count, then you have to (somehow) lock out updates to the `sourceMap` while making the `totalBadRecords` call.  AFAIK, there is no way to do this using (just) the `ConcurrentHashMap` API, and I can't think of a way to do it that doesn't make the map a concurrency bottleneck.

In fact, if you need to calculate accurate counts, you have to use external locking for (at least) the counting operation, and all operations that could change the outcome of the counting.  And even that doesn't deal with the possibility that some thread may modify one of the `TestVO` objects while you are counting records, and cause the `TestVO` to change from "good" to "bad" or vice-versa.

Comment: This method totalBadRecords caling from method and parameters to this method are map objects and they both are final  Still they cause issues

Comment: @user2750658 - That doesn't make any difference.  The problem is more fundamental than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following.

That would guarantee you that *after* a call to the `totalBadRecords` method, the String representing the bad charges in the logMap is accurate, you don't have *lost updates*. Of course a *phantom read* can always happen, as you do not lock the sourceMap.

```
private static final String BAD_RECORDS_KEY = "badRecordsFound:";

    public void totalBadRecords(final ConcurrentMap<Integer, TestVO> sourceMap,
            final ConcurrentMap<String, String> logMap) {

        while (true) {
            // get the old value that is going to be replaced.
            String oldValue = logMap.get(BAD_RECORDS_KEY);

            // calculate new value
            BigDecimal badCharges = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            for (TestVO e : sourceMap.values()) {
                if ("Y".equals(e.getInd()))
                    badCharges = badCharges.add(e.getAmount());
            }
            final String newValue = badCharges.toPlainString();

            // insert into map if there was no mapping before
            if (oldValue == null) {
                oldValue = logMap.putIfAbsent(BAD_RECORDS_KEY, newValue);
                if (oldValue == null) {
                    oldValue = newValue;
                }
            }

            // replace the entry in the map
            if (logMap.replace(BAD_RECORDS_KEY, oldValue, newValue)) {
                // update succeeded -> there where no updates to the logMap while calculating the bad charges.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why we need to replace new value with oldvalue. How it will ensure the threadsafety.For each thread call i am creating new concurrenthashmap object .So each thread have it'w own object reference.

Comment: @user2750658 a `put` on a map replaces the previous value, that's why. `replace` is an [atomic operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). You are creating *new* maps for each thread? Why do you have thread-safeness issues then to begin with? Both maps? Or just one?

Comment: both maps declared in method level and both are final.when each thread reads first they will create their own objects.

Comment: These maps are not created at class level i mean instance variable.These are created within method.